# Geometry nodes animation intersection

Tags: geometry-nodes, intersection

How to remove intersection between those light rays which was made from planes and animated via geometry nodes and a cube.

[image]

I'd like to make an animation when the light rays will be only from the upper side of the cube which is without face. Second screen is a my geometry nodes setup. Thanks

[image]